# PHP fgetcsv() Tab Delimited Isn't working correctly

Tags: php, csv

I have a tab delimited txt file (ex. "US  California  LA")  that needs to be output word for word.  Could anyone help me figure out how to get it to break word for word??

My code:

```
while(($row = fgetcsv($file,"\t")) !== false)
{
    print($row[0]);
}
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => US  California  LA
)
```

From my reading the `fgetcsv` should break each word after the delimiter, which it does do but only for COMMA separated entries looks like below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => US
)
```

Comment: are you sure it has tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delimiter is third parameter of fgetcsv. Try:

```
while(($row = fgetcsv($file, 1000, "\t")) !== false)
{
    print($row[0]);
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Guess I should have read the documentation closer **"It became optional in PHP 5. Omitting this parameter (or setting it to 0 in PHP 5.1.0 and later) the maximum line length is not limited, which is slightly slower."**  I'm using v5.5...  Stupid mistake but thanks for the help!!